# Android Audio MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648)

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am getting Media Player error (1, -2147483648) for my android application with android OS version 4.4.2 (API 19).

```
var audio = new Audio('file:///android_asset/www/audio/arrow.wav');
audio.play();
```

The same content is working with OS version API 23 ,Lollipop Marsh mellow.

Also i am using cordova with this application.

Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you show the code? I am suspecting you are calling Media player methods in wrong order

Comment: I used only the above shown code to play this particular audio. Plz let me know what other information you need ?